# Preserving List value if View Changes in same Controller

Tags: list, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-5

I have been on MVC5 application, where there is a requirement to get some list of records, so i tried creating List type in controller Level, instead of ActionMethod level and in Post Action Method i stored values into them.

Problem is, if i'm staying in same view, list have the Value, but as soon as i Redirect to another view, i'm loosing list records and it becomes null even its redirecting in same Controller's Action Method

Here is my Code:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{  
    //Here i'm Globally creating a List without assigning any memory to it.
    IEnumerable<User> lstUser; 

    public ActionResult BindUser()
    { 
        return View();
    }      

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult BindUser(ProfileUser profileUser)
    {       
        //Here i'll bind DB records into List
        lstUser = db.tablesname.ToList();

        //Here i'm Redirecting him to Another Action Method present in Same Controller
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "UserController"); 
    }  

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        //Here my list Becomes null
        if(lstUser!=null)
        {
            //Do Some thing
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

I can use TempData to store List values but i wanted to know the reason behind list loosing data and becoming null Everytime. Is there any way i could present list loosing its record without becoming null without using any TempData or session.

Comment: The web is stateless. Every time a request is made, a new instance of your controller is initialized, meaning `lstUser` is initialized as an empty collection. You need to persist the values somewhere (preferably in a database)